# Is shape dynamics capable of explaining dark matter?

Tags: general-relativity, dark-matter, modified-gravity, machs-principle

I recently got introduced to the incredibly fascinating subject of Shape Dynamics: for example see https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0105

Shape Dynamics uses conformal three-dimensional geometry to build up any solution of classical physics.
It's completely relational, meaning it doesn't rely on a background space, or background time. It just calculates the position of everything *relative* to each other.
It doesn't postulate spacetime. Time therein is a secondary parameter, just following from the (relative) changes of objects.

Locally, the solutions of General Relativity and Shape Dynamics are equivalent. However, presumably they are *not* equivalent on larger scales and globally.

Has it been tried somewhere to explain dark matter using shape dynamics?
To me, it seems obvious that this need to be done (at least to have a look...), because galaxy scale is the next order of magnitude after solar systems and the predictions of General Relativity deviate from the measurements (without using dark matter) just as the results of Shape Dynamics are supposed to deviate from General Relativity as well on larger scales. However, I didn't find a single remark on dark matter in the texts on shape dynamics. Did I get something wrong here? Or did I oversee a reference where it has been done?

#I would recommend new tags (but cannot introduce them due to credit restrictions) "shape-dynamics" and "relationalism"

Comment: More on [shape dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22shape+dynamics%22).

Comment: I wish the paper was a lot clearer. It has the usual problems that make classical gravity papers incomprehensible to non-gravity people. They never explain the simplest observable sense in which their theory's predictions differ from GR's, but instead they spend dozens of pages rhapsodizing about  unobservable, unphysical concepts like maximally analytically extended solutions.

Comment: That said, if you look at equation 592, you can see that the spherically symmetric solution at large radius looks just like ordinary gravity, which suggests that it has no bearing on the problem of dark matter, or dark energy for that matter. Skimming that section, the effects of shape dynamics seem to be wholly confined to the fine details of the boundaries and interiors of black holes.

Comment: These folks are more like mathematicians and philosophers than physicists, so I'm not surprised there's no connection to experiment made anywhere in the paper. But if I had to guess, I'd say the best way to test this theory would be through imaging a black hole or looking at the gravitational radiation at the end-stage of a black hole merger. Not through low-energy, long-distance stuff like galaxy rotation.

Comment: @knzhou thank you for your insights! Interesting. However, I want to disagree: Things are not that simple. In chapter 13.4, Mercati describes asymptotically flat spacetimes. In that case, it's equivalent to General Relativity solely. However, Shape Dynamics - universes don't _need_ to be asymptotically flat. My question merely refers to those cases.

Comment: Solutions of GR don’t need to be asymptotically flat either… and if you want to explain galaxy rotation curves with weird asymptotic behavior, how could you make those deviations kick in _only_ at the edges of galaxies, then go back to normal between galaxies and within them? That’s some really smart asymptotic behavior!

Comment: If the solutions of GR aren't asymptotically flat they approach dark energy, which doesn't play a role on galaxy scale (And that's not what I mean). What I mean instead is: a background - free description of gravity for galaxies. No flat spacetime as a background for galaxies. No _forced_ asymptotical flatness between galaxies. Galactic rotation curves don't  go back to normal between galaxies, by the way (don't do it from the measurements). And they aren't normal within galaxies (also from the measurements). With "normal" you mean "solar-system-like", btw, Newtonian.